# when using email id in \url it is showing the local drive path in pdf

Tags: hyperref, links, url

When I am using email id in \url it is showing the local drive path in pdf

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{rcvenkatesan@gmail.com}
\end{document}
```

How to remove the local path in the url ? (see the below screenshot)

[image]

Comment: `rcvenkatesan@gmail.com` if used as a URL in any system denotes a relative link to a file called `rcvenkatesan@gmail.com`  did you intent the URL `mailto:rcvenkatesan@gmail.com` ?

Comment: @David,  I need mailto: rcvenkatesan@gmail.com or simply rcvenkatesan@gmail.com, with out the local drive information

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is possible to achieve this by the command \url{} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d suggest to define a command for the purpose of typesetting e-mail addresses:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\mailto}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\mailto{rcvenkatesan@gmail.com}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** This solution assumes that the address doesn’t contain `%`, `#`, or `\` characters (see the manual of the `url` package, p. 1).

Comment: If it's an email address it shouldn't contain anything weird.  Most providers only allow `A-Z`, `0-9`, `.`, `-`, and `_`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Actually, the only problematic characters are `%`, `#`, and `\ `(see edit).